# PHP editor with debug option

Tags: open-source, php, ubuntu, editor

I need a PHP editor like eclipse to debug my codes. Is there any open source available for ubuntu?

Comment: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq+php+ide+linux

Comment: 1) what's wrong with Eclipse 2) do you mean gratis? Why would you want open source unless you intend to change the code? Is that what you want to do? If you don't trust the site you get it from, compare the MD5.

Comment: We can't really help you unless you tell us what features you need. "Like Eclipse" is not a feature list. Eclipse is "like Eclipse" - what's wrong with Eclipse? Please read [ask]

Comment: ***Nothing*** beats [PyCharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/). Since the question is closed, I wont post a long answer, just a 'short comment. I have tried a bunco of Python IDEs. Some are good, but nothing can touch PyCharm. It is all that I use, both personally and professionally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible solution could be

VS Code with PHP Debug plugin

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/php

https://code.visualstudio.com/

[image]

Comment: @ThilakarRaj Is it what you were looking for?

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Sonamor about VSCode. I personally use it all the time. However, there are other alternatives that are also very good, in fact, in my opinion, better than VSCode when it comes to php debugging.

Here's a list of alternatives that will run on Ubuntu:

1. Atom - url: https://atom.io/

   - Github repo: https://github.com/atom/atom
2. KDevelop - https://kdevelop.org
3. Kate - https://kate-editor.org/ide
4. PhpStorm - https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/

. Geany - http://geany.org

I personally use all of them, currently and for php, I prefer PhpStorm above the rest. It's not open source like the others, but well worth the money. However, since you asked for open source, the best for php debugging in my opinion would definitely be Atom.

***Edited to add Geany, suggested by user: ivanivan and YES, I forgot about Geany and it's a great IDE.

Comment: Kate has missing icons/buttons if you aren't running in a KDE desktop (even with all of KDE installed).  Geany is a great replacement, and is cross platform as well.